# How to fix a font error?

Tags: fonts, browser

The screenshot looks like:

[image: browser image]

It happens on Firefox as well as Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a font error - it looks the pretty much the same in Safari on my Mac. The text is stylized with a  tag and the browser is doing its best to render the sans-serif font called in the CSS stylesheet. In Firefox, bring up the Inspector panel (Control-Shift-I) and you can see the HTML element properties for each section on the page.